# Find mean of subsequent rows in pandas data frame if two values have same sign

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a pandas data frame with 4 columns ('string1', 'float1', 'float2', 'string2').'String1' column has repetitive values in consecutive rows. I need to traverse the 'float1' column by every element(i.e. float) and check if it has a +/- operator preceding it. If the operator is different in same values from 'string1' then the entire rows are to be deleted, otherwise, find the mean of 'float1', 'float2', and add the string values from the 'string2' by '|' and 'string1' remains the same.

The data frame looks like this:

```
symbol     logFC     adj.P.Val      ID
A2M     -1.0912438  0.02647898  217757_at
A2M-AS1 -0.8953089  0.01443973  1564139_at
A4GALT  -1.3640826  0.02797254  219488_at
AATBC   -2.2205471  0.00654647  205969_at
AATBC    1.3869134  0.00874959  1563088_a_at
ABCA17P  2.3007386  0.04703096  231164_at
ABCA6   -2.1360694  0.02161093  0082_at
ABCA6   -1.1171276  0.03133593  7504_at
ABCA6   -1.8703369  0.01409799  4719_at
```

I have tried running a for loop for every entry but it is very time consuming and is giving me mean of every value

The expected data frame should be like:

for (AATBC in symbol) logFc has (-2.2205471 & 1.3869134), therefore these two rows are removed because they have different operators

for (ABCA6 in symbol) all logFc has the same operator and therefore we will find the mean (of logfc and adj p.value) and write ID in the same row as follows

```
symbol     logFC     adj.P.Val      ID
A2M     -1.0912438  0.02647898  217757_at
A2M-AS1 -0.8953089  0.01443973  1564139_at
A4GALT  -1.3640826  0.02797254  219488_at
ABCA17P  2.3007386  0.04703096  231164_at
ABCA6   -1.7078446  0.02234828  0082_at | 7504_at | 4719_at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where` to subset to `'symbols'` that are all of the same sign. Then `groupby` + `agg`. This works because `groupby` ignores rows with `NaN` as the keys, which effectively removes groups that change sign from the output.

```
import numpy as np

m = np.sign(df.logFC)  # can map `0` if you want to consider that + or -

(df.where(m.groupby(df.symbol).transform('nunique') == 1)
   .groupby('symbol')
   .agg({'logFC': 'mean', 'adj.P.Val': 'mean', 'ID': ' | '.join})
)
```

---

```
            logFC  adj.P.Val                           ID
symbol                                                   
A2M     -1.091244   0.026479                    217757_at
A2M-AS1 -0.895309   0.014440                   1564139_at
A4GALT  -1.364083   0.027973                    219488_at
ABCA17P  2.300739   0.047031                    231164_at
ABCA6   -1.707845   0.022348  0082_at | 7504_at | 4719_at
```

Comment: very clear concise answer. Definitely better than what I was brewing up.

Comment: As it stands, it does rely on creating unique symbol groups, regardless of whether or not they are consecutive. if symbols can be repeated later on and should be placed into separate groups, I can modify the solution. But if it's plainly sorted on `'symbol'`, which it appears to be, then this will work.